# In Anki, how to search for all cards scheduled for today?

Tags: anki

I would like to use a filtered deck to study all different subjects I have in Anki at once, using other decks to mainly control review/new cards flow of a particular topic (via deck options).

My problem is that search `is:due` only finds cards that are to be reviewed today (as opposed to learnt) and `is:new` matches all unseen cards.

So, what search term would return all cards that are scheduled for today, including review and new ones?
Studying `default` deck proved unsatisfactory as the order of cards was predictable, very much so in AnkiDroid.

Comment: Relevant manual section: https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#searching

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to the [tag:anki] text, questions should be about the `anki` API or SDK, not about using the application.

Answer (score 3):

**For Anki Version < 2.0**

```
(is:new or is:due)
```

This search will give you a filtered deck that includes cards due today as well as *all* new cards.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to have a filtered deck that includes all cards *due* today as well as only the number of *new* cards that you want to use from the deck settings. I have looked for a way to do this for some time but have not yet found a way to do so. my solution is to use a deck to randomize the order of my reviews:

```
is:due
(Selected by: Random)
```

If you then put this filtered deck and your deck with new cards in the same parent deck, you can study using the parent deck to mix the new cards and reviews.

**Edit: 2020-06, for Anki Version > 2.1**

[Anki Scheduler V2.1](https://anki.tenderapp.com/kb/anki-ecosystem/the-anki-21-scheduler) now supports this directly by allowing decks with two criteria.

Comment: However, this breaks with the decks that contains subdecks, right?

With subdecks, Anki will take new cards in the alphabetical order of the subdects. But this seems to take random cards from all subdecks equally.